# Catalog Rule Round rule_price of catalogrule_product_price

Tags: magento-1.8, database, catalog-price-rules, price-rules, catalog-rules

How i can round rule_price from table catalogrule_product_price ?

i try to change calcPriceRule from Mage_CatalogRule_Helper_Data, no results!

have you an idea of what function save rule_price in catalogrule_product_price ?

Thanx

Comment: What would be the rounding rule? Nearest dollar, quarter, etc? Do you have any core edits to the code or extensions that interact/override with the Catalog Price rules?

Comment: I want to round to the nearest dollar for catalog price rules. I have any core edits and no extension for catalog rules.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest would be to hook into the event `catalog_product_get_final_price` and just round the price to the amount you want.

[How to implement observers](http://www.apptha.com/blog/magento-observers-and-dispatching-events-explained-explicitly/)

Is there anywhere on Magento.stackexchange a great answer how to implement an observer I can link to for the future? To lazy to write it down all the time, please add the link to the comments

Comment: Your methods can actually work, but is not recommended by Magento I think! 

You change the rendering of the front without changing the values ​​in the database. 

If I change the functions on the event catalog_product_get_final_price, i change only render! 

I want to change the value when it is saved or calculated. 

Do you understand the difference between ?

Comment: Did you try this? I'm quite sure, that the method is called _before_ the price is copied to the quote item?

Answer (score 1):

You can see this `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer`, function `processFrontFinalPrice` it's called when get final price, so you can change something in this.

```
if (!isset($this->_rulePrices[$key])) {
    $rulePrice = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule')
        ->getRulePrice($date, $wId, $gId, $pId);
    $this->_rulePrices[$key] = $rulePrice;
}
```

By override model observer.

Some articles, maybe [relate to](http://shop.mincoding.com/mystoreonline/blog/magento-catalog-rule-prices/)

Comment: Your methods can actually work, but is not recommended by Magento I think! 

You change the rendering of the front without changing the values ​​in the database. 

If I change the functions on the event catalog_product_get_final_price, i change only render! 

I want to change the value when it is saved or calculated. 

Do you understand the difference between ?

Comment: Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule') get data from data via getRulePrice, so you can check if you want round something.

Comment: If you like when update to database you can check Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Action_Index_Refresh class, it's used for calculation before saving to database