# How to change product price calculation?

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, checkout, catalog, price

I would like to add an additional fee to a product. This fee will then be calculated on top of the product's price. So in the catalog the regular product price will be displayed, and in the cart/checkout/emails/etc the price+addedfee will be displayed.
Any specials or discounts will have to apply to the product's price only, and not the additional fee.

so basically I want the final price to be:

`price = (magentos-calculated-product-price) + added-fee + tax-over-both`

and in the cart I want to display for each item:

`name | amount | unit price | added fee | subtotal`

I know how to create a custom product attribute and how to sync that attribute to a quote and then an order. Also, editing the templates is not a problem.

What I would like to know is how and where should I do the price calculation? Should I use an event (which one?) or should I overwrite a core model?

There seem to be many different ways to accomplish this, and I don't want to break discount calculation or admin functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if your fee is flat using a shopping cart price rule may be a good option.

Otherwise you can use `catalog_product_get_final_price` event.

Comment: looks like this might be the way to go. For some reason however, in my even observer, the product gotten from `$observer->getEvent()->getProduct()` does not contain a custom attribute that I have added. Do you know why this might be? (the attribute works fine everywhere else)

Comment: This sounds like a new question ;)

Comment: lol fair enough. Thanks for your answer, it looks like it's the way to go and if I can get this attribute thing working, I will mark it as accepted. For anyone interested, i asked the question here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21570/why-is-my-products-custom-attribute-not-available-during-this-event

Comment: Someone helped me out with that and now it all works. Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price` model and overwrite the `getFinalPrice()` method.

Comment: I have just tested this and it seems to work fine. Is there any event that you know of that I could use instead? (So I won't have to modify core files)

Answer (score 0):

It is not the same question, but I think the same answer:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/21431/217
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/21441/217

If you want to have this fee on order level, you might want to implement your own total model for this.